# Rails/SimpleForm: How do I nest fields for has_many associations in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

My model accepts nested attributes for a `has_many` association.

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :job_references
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
```

I want fields for multiple `job_references` on the new employee form.

My controller looks like this:

```
  class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
    def new
      @employee = employee.new
      2.times { @employee.job_references.build }
    end
```

I have this in my form:

```
<%= form.simple_fields_for :job_references do |job_references_form| %>
  <%= job_references_form.simple_fields_for(:job_reference) do |job_reference_form| %>
    <%= job_reference_form.input :name, label: "Name" %>
    <%= job_reference_form.input :company %>
    <%= job_reference_form.input :role %>
    <%= job_reference_form.input :phone_number %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I want the form to display to lots of inputs, representing two job reference records. However, the form renders with a set of fields for only one job reference.

How can I ensure that the form displays two sets of fields?

Answer (score 0):

You could create `@job_reference_1` and `@job_reference_2` instance variables in your controller and then have a seperate `simple_fields_for` block for each one.  If you want to get more complicated you could use [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) or [stimulus](https://stimulusjs.org/) to dynamically add or remove the nested fields.

You also might be able to use @job_references = 2.times { @employee.job_references.build } in your controller. Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qM4ZK0uuZUE) that shows how to do the nested forms dynamically.